# Using tcmalloc/jemalloc with custom memory pool manager

Tags: c, memory, allocator, tcmalloc

I would like to use a high performance general purpose allocator like `jemalloc`/`tcmalloc` with a memory pool. Is there a guide for doing this? I don't want to use `jemalloc`/`tcmalloc` as a drop-in replacement for `malloc`.

I have memory pool that uses `libarena` and carves a largish memory area (2GB). I want to create fixed size objects pool like `gslice` on this arena for say 1 GB. (like the Bonwick slab allocator) and want to use the rest of the memory for variable sized general purpose allocation. I would like to have `jemalloc`/`tcmalloc` use this memory area. Is this possible? Any ideas as to how I can proceed? If there is an alternate library, I would like to hear about it as well.

Comment: Good luck getting this answered, I have also really wanted this answered, please see my http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341587/malloc-like-function-using-custom-heap own question.

Comment: I wrote an allocator specifically for our app.  One thing that turned out to be a real nifty idea was the concept of reducing all possible allocations to a small number of "quantum" sizes.  Below 4k = 8 bytes, 4k..16k = 16 byte... up to 64mb max.  I ended up with only had about 1000 different sizes all the way up to 64 MB.  Wasted ram was low since the size of the wasted space was a function of the size of the allocation.  This allowed recycle piles for each size.  A free was just a push and an alloc was a pop, unless the pile was empty for that size.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but you may find some useful info on this jemalloc thread regarding allocating memory as additional arenas for custom allocators here: http://www.canonware.com/pipermail/jemalloc-discuss/2015-January/000988.html

Answer (score 8):

This is an old question, but there's finally a positive answer, at least where `jemalloc` is concerned. Since `jemalloc` version 4.0.0, you can use `mallctl` to set hooks for where chunked allocations get memory by using the `arena.<i>.chunk_hooks` interface. These hooks are well documented in the [jemalloc manpage](http://www.canonware.com/download/jemalloc/jemalloc-latest/doc/jemalloc.html#arena.i.chunk_hooks), including a number of cross-references.

I'm unaware as to any similar interface in `tcmalloc`; I do not use it.

I answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30836359/jemalloc-mmap-and-shared-memory) semi-recently; there may be useful information there, as well.