# malloc like function using custom heap

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

What would be the best approach in C if I wish to construct malloc like functionality with a custom pre-allocated heap?

My specific issue here is that I have a mmap-able (memory like) device which has been placed into my address space but I need to attain a more flexible way of using this memory to store objects which will be allocated and freed over time.

I know that malloc, free and the other similar functions are used to perform this kind of allocation on the heap but is there any way to use the logic provided by this kind of function for its dynamic behaviour while providing my own address space to operate as the heap in question?

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question, but it sounds to me like you're looking for something like [linux's `clone` function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html), which is similar to fork, but it allows you to pass a stack to that child proccess

Comment: Well, what kind of memory management do you need? The full generality of `malloc` & `free`? Or do you obey a stack discipline (first allocated, first freed)? Perhaps you can restrict yourself to allocations of a single size and make a *pool*?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Thank you for your comment, unfortunately this is not quite what I am getting at. Essentially, I have a custom memory mapped device which I wish to use as a "heap" for memory allocations. I am looking for a way to run a memory allocator on this device instead of the normal heap. This is not in this case to allow IPC, just because I need to have the data stored on a particular device.

Comment: @delnan I can probably manage allocations of a single size (the objects are quite large so the overhead from rounding up to a page would be minimal) however a stack is likely not ok. Objects are not likely to be freed in a predictable order. I am a little surprised there is not a fairly simple way of doing this given all the logic is there in the standard libraries, just no way to point them to a custom back-end. Thanks for your comment however.

Comment: So you are probably looking for a memory pooling library? you know that malloc and free often use some memory close to your allocation. if this is an mmapable device you best not do that if this is then transferred to somewhere else.

Comment: @Alex Doing a little googling this does seem to be the sort of thing that would help fix my issue. So just to clarify, if I had a "memory pool" like this it would allow me to pass it an address range it may use then I would be able to allocate and free areas of this memory pool to hold data? Though I do not quite understand your second point about malloc and free using memory close to my allocation, could you elaborate on that slightly please?

Comment: @Vality it strongly depends on the memory pool implementation. `C++` has primitives (placement new, per class operator new overloading) that give you very fine grained control over memory. I'm sure similar things in `c` exist as  well. look at: http://mirror.fsf.org/pmon2000/2.x/src/lib/libc/malloc.c this is the K&R C Textbook `malloc` implementation. every allocation is prefixed by a header, that would then be in your region. if you want to avoid this (because your mapped region has context to another entity) you'd have to have a list or stack of pointers.

Comment: On Windows, there are custom heaps. They can be used for several use cases, such as: create custom heaps where all objects have same size (to help with inner fragmentation) or create fixed size heaps (to prevent an application from using more memory than it is supposed to. The Unix* worlds did not recognize yet, that this is a very useful feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) has stateful allocators suitable for shared memory segments: they may be re-usable for other mmapped address ranges too.

Otherwise, you may need to roll your own. In increasing order of complexity, you could consider:

1. a simple arena allocator: this is almost trivial, but has no way to free individual objects and reuse their memory
2. a simple object pool allocator: this works for fixed-size objects with almost no overhead (assuming the object is at least as large as a pointer, you can maintain a singly-linked list of freed objects)
3. a hybrid system with multiple object pools for different sizes (but each pool is individually a simple fixed-size instance)
4. some kind of slab/slub allocator (multiple fixed-size pools sharing a simple underlying allocator of large fixed-size slabs)
5. a [SLOB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLOB) allocator
6. a full malloc/free implementation (several are open source, so you can take an implementation and rip out anything you don't need).

Which of those are suitable will depend on some information you haven't given:

- object size

  - object pools work if you have only one, or only a few, sizes of object to allocate
  - arena allocators don't care about object size
  - neither support `realloc`
- object lifetime

  - object pools generally support arbitrary malloc/free sequences
  - arenas usually allow deallocation only all-at-once (so you just reset the arena to an empty state). You could modify this to allow LIFO deallocation.
- space/performance tradeoffs

  - the full heap implementation will probably be the slowest and most complex, but is also the most flexible
  - SLOB is easier and lighter-weight, but suffers more from fragmentation

Answer (score 2):

`malloc` and family is a rather complex set of library functions. They do a lot of bookkeeping like which parts of the heap are in use and such.

A relatively easy way to use the standard memory allocator `malloc` is to remap the default heap with your custom mapping.

```
void * part_of_heap = memalign(sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE), nbytes);
void * ret = mmap(part_of_heap, nbytes
             , PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_FIXED, fd, 0);
if (ret == MAP_FAILED) {/* ... */}
free(part_of_heap);
```

Now anything that is placed in the area `part_of_heap`-`part_of_heap+nbytes` by malloc will go into your own mapped area. This is unsupported though and will not guarantee that any allocations will actually go there.

Otherwise you would need to implement your own memory allocator, which has to do bookkeeping. A linked list would do for starters. I know of no open implementation that would serve your needs.